# Having trouble adding New AD Users using a ForEach loop

Tags: powershell, foreach, active-directory

I'm dipping my toes into PowerShell for the first time with a course, but I'm having some issues making the program work the way I need it to. The program, from top to bottom, is supposed to:

1. Create a Finance OU, or delete it and make another one if already extant
2. Bring in a CSV file
3. Populate the new OU with Users using only the specified data types
4. Make a data table
5. bring in a different CSV file
6. populate the table with the information from the new CSV

Easy stuff that I'm certain a baby could accomplish, but for some reason I'm stuck like glue.
The program I wrote after bouncing my head off of it for a while has no problem with 1, 2, 4, 5 and 6, but for some reason it's having the hardest time making the ADusers with the CSV file. The best result I ever got was getting only the first entry. Errors specify that ADUser already exists when checking the first entry. This is impossible, since it's deleted and recreated every time. Here's the code I wrote:

```
# start with a nice clean slate
Clear

# OU path declaration
$Path = "OU=Finance,DC=consultingfirm,DC=com"

# If we've already made it, delete Finance OU and make a new one
if ([adsi]::Exists("LDAP://$Path")) 
{
    Write-Host "$Path already exists.  Deleting and recreating"
    Remove-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity $Path -Recursive -confirm:$false
} 

New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name Finance -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $False
Write-Host "created $Path"

# setting variables for ForEach loop
$NewAD = Import-CSV $PSScriptRoot\financePersonnel.csv
$Path = "OU=Finance,DC=consultingfirm,DC=com"

# import personnel data
Try 
{
ForEach ($ADUser in $NewAD)
{
$First = $ADUser.First_Name
$Last = $ADUser.Last_Name
$Name = $First + " " + $Last
$Postal = $ADUser.PostalCode
$Office = $ADUser.OfficePhone
$Mobile = $ADUser.MobilePhone

Write-Host "I see $Name"
New-ADUser -GivenName $First -Surname $Last -Name $Name -PostalCode $Postal -OfficePhone $Office -MobilePhone $Mobile -Path $Path
}
}
Catch [System.OutOfMemoryException] {"Exception occured: I ran out of memory!"}

# Create the new database in the server by using SQL
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance .\SQLEXPRESS -InputFile $PSScriptRoot\dbcreate.sql

#. Use the table SQL file I made to format the table
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance .\SQLEXPRESS -Database ClientDB -InputFile $PSScriptRoot\client_A_Contacts.sql

#. Name the variables for table input
$table = 'dbo.Client_A_Contacts'
$db = 'ClientDB'

#. Importing data to table

Try{
    Import-CSV $PSScriptRoot\NewClientData.csv | ForEach-Object { Invoke-Sqlcmd `
        -Database $db -ServerInstance ".\SQLEXPRESS" -Query "Insert into $table (first_name,last_name,city,county,postal_code,office_phone,mobile_phone) `
        VALUES ('$($_.first_name)','$($_.last_name)','$($_.city)','$($_.county)','$($_.zip)','$($_.officePhone)','$($_.mobilePhone)')"}
}
Catch [System.OutOfMemoryException] {"Exception occured: I ran out of memory!"}
```

Even on a brand new creation of the OU, it says the first one already exists, and fails to do any of the others. If you comment out the New-ADUser line, however, it will print the name of every individual on the CSV. I had added previously a check to see if an entry exists, and to delete and recreate it if so. This is what that looked like:

```
$AlreadyMade = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '$Name'"
    $MakeTheUser = New-ADUser -GivenName $First -Surname $Last -Name $Name -DisplayName $Name `
        -PostalCode $Postal -MobilePhone $Mobile -OfficePhone $Office -Path $Path

    #Check to make sure the program identifies the user
    Write-Host "I see $Name"
    
    #If user exists, delete and recreate. If it doesn't, just make it
    if($null -eq $AlreadyMade)
    {
    $MakeTheUser
    Write-Host "$name has been added as a user!"
    }

    else
    {
    $AlreadyMade | Remove-ADUser -Confirm:$false
    $MakeTheUser
    Write-Host "$name has been deleted and then added as a user!"
    }
    }
```

But boy did that not work. I think one time I got a fully populated first data entry (skipping the other several hundred afterward), but it only worked once, despite the OU being deleted and recreated every time the program runs.

I could dearly use some educated eyes on this, as I'm having no luck. I added the Write-Host lines to debug a bit. I've tried using a ForEach-Object instead of just ForEach, I've tried un-splatting the variables, I've probably tried other things I can't quite remember, but I'm just getting blood on the screen and nothing in the nice new OU.
I genuinely look forward to learning about the stupid error I made and how simple the fix will be. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I would break down the code in separate steps first. For instance, simply try out the `New-ADUser` part first on a single testuser in a known OU. If that fails, read the exception that is thrown, repair that bit and if that works, proceed with the next part etc. P.S. I hope this is all in a test environment and you are not killing and recreating OU's and users in a production environment.. Even after recreating with the same name, the users will have different SID's and will **not** be the same as the removed users..

Comment: Yes, all in a virtualized test environment

Comment: So as said, test your `New-ADUser` part in a separate script. Append `-ErrorAction Stop` and do a 'plain' `catch { throw }`. That will tell you what went wrong. (or leave out the `try{..} catch{..}` so you will see what errors you get if any on that part. Perhaps not a bad idea to also set the new users `SamAccountName` ?

Comment: Look at the logic in your second code. You blindly try to create a new user in the second line **without checking** if that user already exists (which you try to find out in the first line). You finish with `"$name has been deleted and then added as a user!"`, but in fact you do the opposite.